# Who knows which files should be included in a website?

Tags: apache, http

When the browser requests a website, any website from a HTTP server, which of the two parses the site's content in order to know which other files need to be included on the webpage?

What I mean is this:

1. the browser asks for the `html` file and then observers that it needs to import some external `css` files and HE is the one who requests them.

**OR**

1. the HTTP server when faced with a request for a website, parses (already knows) which sites need to be linked to a certain webpage and sends them alongside the `html` page?

I'm guessing the first case is the correct one, but if someone can confirm and maybe clarify it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Both answers are correct, and if you have any developer tools enabled on your browser (for example, in Chrome you can get to the developer tools with `CTRL+SHIFT+I`) you can inspect the network tab to see further details of all the requests that are being made from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all done by the client (which is usually a browser). When it sees `<script>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<link>`, etc. tags that reference other documents, it downloads them if necessary.

Comment: Or decides not to download them, as the case may be. For example, `curl http://example.com/page.html` will fetch `page.html` and nothing else; a browser without image support will not need to download images, etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia -

> The primary function of a web server is to cater web page to the
>   request of clients using the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP). This
>   means delivery of HTML documents and any additional content that may
>   be included by a document, such as images, style sheets and scripts.

and

> The primary purpose of a web browser is to bring information resources
>   to the user ("retrieval" or "fetching"), allowing them to view the
>   information ("display", "rendering"), and then access other
>   information ("navigation", "following links").

It is the Browser that parses the HTML and request for the associated contents.